# Why does React Native reimplement XMLHttpRequest when it is in JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

When browsing through the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) I noticed that XMLHttpRequest is reimplmented in both java and objective-c and then wrapped with js. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Network). Why? If JavaScriptCore (as mentioned in their [page on the javascript enviroment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html)) supports XMLHttpRequest, why bother reinventing the wheel and just use the version that already exists?

Does it increase performance?

Comment: The premise of this question is incorrect. JavaScriptCore does not have XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's written to support mobile platforms efficiently, and they even have mentions of ios platforms inparticular in their XMLHttpRequest implementation.

Also, from their docs:

> XMLHttpRequest API is implemented on-top of iOS networking apis. The notable difference from web is the security model: you can read from arbitrary websites on the internet since there is no concept of CORS.
>
> The security model for XMLHttpRequest is different than on web as there is no concept of CORS in native apps.

Comment: Ah CORS! That makes a lot of sense. There's no good reason that a native app should deal with those restrictions. Thanks!